# Login system using Identity and role provider for existing database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

For the past few days, I was working in creating a login system for a webApp(asp.Net MVC 5) where I have a database already with username, credentials and Roles. I have found information from many blogs and stack overflow questions for my work and used it accordingly. Now before going online, I want to make sure that this login system is a secure one. I also want to know if there are some improvements which I can implement for this purpose.

For Authentication, I have implemeted as shown in the below article https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Custom-Database-and-OWIN/. For Authorization, I have used Role Provider and implemented few required methods as like one shown below:

```
public class RoleList:RoleProvider
{
     public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
     {
            if (username == null || username == "")
                throw new ProviderException("User name cannot be empty or null.");
            if (roleName == null || roleName == "")
                throw new ProviderException("Role name cannot be empty or null.");

            bool userIsInRole = false;
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            String mycon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; 
            String myquery = 
                "SELECT " +
                    "r.RName, u.UName " +
                "FROM " +
                    "Users u " +
                "INNER JOIN " +
                    "UserRole ur " +
                "ON " +
                    "u.Id=ur.UserId " +
                "INNER JOIN " +
                    "Roles r " +
                "ON " +
                    "ur.RoleId=r.Id " +
                "WHERE " +
                    "u.UName=@UName " +
                "AND " +
                    "r.Name=@RName";
            var paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
            paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@UName", username));
            paramList.Add(new SqlParameter("@RName", roleName));
            using (var reader = HelperClasses.DatabaseUtil.GetReader(myquery, mycon, paramList))
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    userIsInRole = true;
                }
            }

            return userIsInRole;
        }
}
```

**In Database**
In the database, I have 4 tables storing below information respectively.

1. user(name and Id) and hash password(using Bcrypt).
2. Roles.
3. Users and Roles mapping.
4. Salt with user id

**In Login Controller**

Login:

1. Get salt and hash from database using inputed user name.
2. Adding salt to the inputed plain text password.
3. Validating the password by inputing hash and salted password to Bcrypt.
4. If success, user will be authenticated by custom sign in manager as shown below

```
CustomSignInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
```

Log Off:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{ 
   HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut    
                             (DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);     
   return RedirectToAction("Index","Login");
}
```

**To authorize an action**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

As, it is an important segment in the application, I wish to know the pros and cons of it. I simplified the question as much as possible for easy understanding to readers. Is this the right way for a login system in asp.NET MVC 5? Can I do anything better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good to me.

1. Password should **not** be stored in the database as plain text
2. All endpoints should be covered by authentication, except for login/reset password and landing page etc.
3. Sensitive data like passwords should not be stored on the client
4. There should be a timeout on the login
5. Use an  up-to-date framework where possible

If you are concerned about security you also need to consider basic website hardening techniques.  For example, make sure that any data which comes from a user input field is cleansed before it is inserted into the database.  Some websites provide free security reports such as [securityheaders.com](https://securityheaders.com/).

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. Of course I don't store passwords in plain text. My passwords are salted and hashed with bcrypt in the database. I use code factor 15 in bcrypt. Also I don't store passwords or any similar things on the client side. I will add the timeout. Many thanks for this. I always keep my frameworks up to date. Thank you.